# IE color: transparent; question

Tags: css, transparency

I'm working on a project where I have to override both embedded styles and primary style sheets in order to change a design. I've got everything working in all the main browsers/versions except for a submit button where the client wants a specific image for the button. I'm using background url to bring in the image, but there is "submit" text in the html that can't be removed from the template because we don't have access. I set color to transparent but it still displays text over the button in IE is there any way to remove this text via css?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Just throwing this out there but you can remove the text completely with JavaScript.

Comment: I found something that worked, but this sounds more proper, I'll google it and look into it for the future. I don't know much javascript but I'll be doing more of these template overrides in the future so i should learn this. Thanks for the pointer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try giving the button a `text-indent: -9999px'

Comment: Would this blow up the block though?

Comment: It shouldn't do that. If it does, you can use `overflow: hidden`

Comment: I feel so dirty for having to do it, but everything else is hacked or !important so why not, It worked!!

Comment: I think !important is a lot more dirty than this.. :P

Comment: It seems better to use a negative indent, that'll make sure no stretching happens :)

Comment: I just gave it an absolute width :) thanks for the help!